# Dependency for Conversion of EPSG 4326 to EPSG 32644 In Android

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid, geoserver, qgis

[image]Actually I am trying to convert EPSG 4326 point(Lat, long) to Epsg 32644(Meters).I am hitting GeoServer to fetch featureData which is in EPSG 32644 format.

For that conversion, I need to import one library i.e QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem. But I am unable add dependency file. Can anyone please guide me?

[image]

Comment: Please explain your problem in broad and post stack trace what issue your facing.

Comment: How to add dependency in gradle file